# javascript or jquery countdown timer demo sample code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working for a quiz application using php, mysql, javascript and jquery.

*I want to create a timer* in which I can set how many mins:secs.
The timer should also be able to show a warning when you have less that 20 seconds left:
**20 seconds left to attempt or finish!**

Suppose if I kept it for three minutes..that will be 180 secs...when it reaches to 160 secs... a pop up message should come to inform that you have only 20 secs left to attempt or finish

Some suggestions, demo links that you know would be appreciated.

Comment: Wiped all the comments here. To Change Chethan: It is absolutely correct that you should try to include more information when posting questions; this helps you not only get answers at all - but helps  you get *better* answers. It also helps people coming along in the future who have the same problem as you.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with this:

```
var countdown = {
    counter:undefined,
    seconds:5, //total seconds left for the countdown
    warning:1, //when seconds==warning show message
    alert: function() {
        //whatever your warning message should do
        console.log("Hurry up!");
    },
    count: function() {
        //tic tac
        this.seconds = this.seconds-1;
        if (this.seconds==this.warning) {
            this.alert();
        }
        if (this.seconds==0) {
            clearInterval(this.counter);
            this.finished();
        }
        console.log(this.seconds+" remaining");
    },
    finished: function() {
        //no more seconds left!
        console.log("Game over!");
    }
};
//start the countdown
countdown.counter = setInterval( function(){ countdown.count(); }, 1000 );
```

Change the **alert** function so that it does what you want. You can also change the **count** function so that it shows remaining seconds in a `div` instead of the console.
And of course, change both `seconds:5` and `warning:1` to 180 and 20 for example.

Hope it works, let me know if I'm missing anything.

*@user2331153 consider this my "welcome to StackOverflow" message, and accept also a friendly advice: Try to demonstrate some effort before asking here. Post some code you have tried, some links you have found, and write an elaborated question, not just 3 lines with errors. That would help both you and SO. Good luck!*

Comment: nice job. Keep up man

Comment: thank u..i wil check it

Comment: @TheBronx that's very nice encouragement. You are really showing what's inside of you. Let's hope we can help this user

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but it sounds like you just need a timeout:

```
minutes = 3;
seconds_left_warning_time = 20;
setTimeout(function() { alert('you only have ' + seconds_left_warning_time + ' seconds left'); }, (minutes*60*1000) - (seconds_left_warning_time*1000));
```

Comment: ohh...ok...thank u ..i wil check it